# How to display an image in Opencart Updated Order Mail?

Tags: php, image, url, opencart2.x

The code below is a default update order mail form which simply display instructions texts. How to add a logo at the top?

```
        if ($order_info['order_status_id'] && $order_status_id && $notify) {
            $language = new Language($order_info['language_code']);
            $language->load($order_info['language_code']);
            $language->load('mail/order');

            $subject = sprintf($language->get('text_update_subject'), html_entity_decode($order_info['store_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'), $order_id);


            $message  = $language->get('text_update_order') . ' ' . $order_id . "\n";
            $message .= $language->get('text_update_date_added') . ' ' . date($language->get('date_format_short'), strtotime($order_info['date_added'])) . "\n\n";

            ...
```

I'd like to add the url above the

> $message  = $language->get('text_update_order') . ' ' . $order_id . "\n";

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to make html code, simply render your data in html and then add`$mail->setHtml($message);`
instead of `$mail->setText($message);`